# JAVA. Чтение из строк файла и запись обратно

Tags: java

У меня есть функция на умножение двух матриц.

Mне необходимо:

1. Прочитать с файла `.txt`  вот так записанные две матрицы

   ```
   [1,2,3;4,5,6;][9,8;7,-6;50,61;]
   ```
2. Умножить их
3. Ответ записать, но уже в другой файл `out.txt` , так же само

   ```
   [173,179;371,368;]
   ```

Код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] mA = 
        {{1,2,3},
         {4,5,6}};

    int[][] mB = 
        {{9,8},
         {7,-6},
         {50,61}};


    int m = mA.length;
    int n = mB[0].length;
    int o = mB.length;
    int[][] res = new int[m][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < o; k++) {
                res[i][j] += mA[i][k] * mB[k][j]; 
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < res[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.format("%6d ", res[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте о регулярных выражениях 
1) Просто читаете из файла все как string 
2) Разбиваете на подстроки которые разделены знаком ";" 
2) Каждую подстроку разбиваете на числа разделенные запятой

Т.е. нужен метод который исходную строку разбивает на массив подстрок
И метод который из этих подстрок будет выбивать числа и преобразовывать их в float, а потом пихать в массив чисел

```
String line = "[13,1,-4; 3,1,5; 2,1,5;]"
String[] rows = getRows(line); //разбивает строку на массив подстрок разд. ";"
float[][] matr = new float[n][m]; 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matr[i][] = getRow(rows[i]); // Возвращает массив чисел разд. "," из подстроки
}
```

Методы getRow, getRows я надеюсь вы сможете написать. Просто изучите регулярные выражения. Очень полезная штука

Что бы записать все в выходной файл:

```
String res = "[";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        res += matr[i][j] + ",";
    }
    res += ";";
}
res += "]"
```

Надеюсь как к файлам подключится и делать запись, вы знаете.
По крайней мере в интернете полно статей, мануалов, и даже видео

Comment: извините, но это был мой первый код на Java, перед этим программировал только на С, и я не совсем понял о чем вы говорите.

Comment: Оу, ну в таком случае вам нужно подтянуть еще саму Java, и хотя бы основы ООП. Но в основном сам алгоритм что в С что на Джава будет тот же, просто нужно учитывать синтаксис языков. А вот на счёт регулярных выражений это не касается конкретного языка в целом. Они вроде бы есть и в С. Просто начните изучать эту тему с 0. А далее поймете все сами :) 
Это не очень сложная тема, да и полезная